# Knockout js checked binding

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to knockout and am a little baffled with regards to checkbox binding. I have the following HTML:

```
 <input id="Category-2039842085241261997" type="checkbox" value="203984,208524,1261997" data-bind="checked:toggleActivation">
 <label for="Category-2039842085241261997">Camis</label>

 <input id="Category-203984208524715507" type="checkbox" value="203984,208524,715507">
 <label for="Category-203984208524715507" data-bind="checked:toggleActivation">Crop Tops</label>
```

In jQuery in order to get the id of the checkbox you would do:

```
$('#menu-right').on('click', 'input', function(e) {
  console.log($(this).prop('id'));
}
```

How do I go about getting this in knockout when I bound a checked event to the checkboxes it actually selected all of the options rather than the one clicked on.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/speedster/96Jth/)

Thanks

Comment: can you show your knockout code?

Comment: I have added a jsFiddle to this showing a basic list. It selects all elements of the list. I want by default to have it unselected. Upon clicking a checkbox I want to get its value/id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

toggleActivation should be observableArray.

```
var viewModel = {
   toggleActivation: ko.observableArray([])
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/96Jth/1/

Comment: I can see from your fiddle that you have added - <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(toggleActivation)"></pre> to get the values to display. Upon clicking of the checkbox how would I use the value to run another function for example

Comment: You can subscribe to toggleActivation or make computed observable.

Comment: Thanks, one last question. I now have the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/speedster/96Jth/4/) I want to get the id of the element that has been click I know you can do this by using event.target.id and change self.togggleActivation to self.toggleActivation= function(data,event) {} what do I do with ko.observableArray([])?

Answer (score 0):

you are not using knockout.js. its a simple HTML and JAVASCRIPT function.knockout have a property called data-bind which bind the data and retrieve the data for you.
here is the code for your understanding.
have a look at this site and first get the basic gyan about knocout working with checkbox. 
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html
good luck.